# create a table with additional null column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a table and wrote following code

```
create table trial as(
  SELECT l2_group AS Customer
       , null  AS Contact 
    FROM ACCT_MASKED_sep17_V1) ;
```

It's giving me an error when I run with create table where as select query runs.

How can I get the result

Comment: "an error" is not helpful. Oracle gives you a nice error number and text with it, and you can use both to search for similar issues (before posting here).

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a data type for that `NULL` column. For example:

```
create table t1 as
  select 1 as c1
       , cast(null as number) as c2 
     from dual

Table created.
```

If as a datatype for the `NULL` column you choose `VARCHAR2(length)` datatype, the length needs to be greater than `0`.